# Como lidar com números maiores que o tipo FLOAT em Python-3.x

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tendo problemas com o tipo de dado FLOAT em Python. Tenho um algoritmo que gera números muito grande, mas o tipo FLOAT não os suporta. Veja:

```
 35             denominadorP = fatorial(p)
 36 
---> 37         resultado = numerador / denominadorP
 38 
 39         return resultado

*OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float*
```

Queria saber se há alguma biblioteca que me ajude a contornar isso. No caso eu gero os números e gravo eles em um arquivo **.txt**

Answer (score -1):

Já que irá gravar em um arquivo txt você poderia tentar resolvendo da seguinte maneira 
`resultado = str(numerador / denominadorP)
f = open('resultado_denominador_fatorial.txt', 'w') #cria o arquivo com permissão de escrita
f.write(resultado)
f.close()`